EMC considerations for external LEDs PCB
I am developing a PCB that has mounted LEDs and their current-limiting resistors. The PCB is 2-layered (bottom layer for GND, top layer for signals and components). It takes the LED control signals and the GND from an external main PCB, which also houses the driving circuit (the MOSFETs and MCU). The cables that connect the main PCB with this PCB are about 30cm long. The LEDs are mid-powered LEDs with a 3V forward voltage.
For this design, I have some questions, mostly from an EMC perspective, such as:

Which is better from an EMC/EMI point of view? Driving the LEDs at high-side (GND always connected to the external LED PCB, control signals on/off) or at low-side (LEDs anode always at power supply with no GND reference when not active, that means most of the time).
Also from an EMC perspective, is it better to drive PWM or constant current? Does the PWM traveling through the cables add EMI to the circuit that can degrade the LED's lifetime?


Constant current is always preferable over PWM in terms of EMI. Anything that oscillates is an EMI source.

@Lundin, You should write this reply, I'll vote for it. I would add that any rapid variation (of current or voltage) is a EMI source (respectively of inductive or capacitive coupling).

Trouble is proportional to di/dt multiplied by the area of the current loop.
If you drive your LEDs with constant voltage PWM with MOSFETs and a current setting resistor, then to limit di/dt:

The MOSFET should have a high enough gate resistor and switch slowly like "a few µs". This is the most critical. In fact it pretty much guarantees you'll be fine. Whereas if you don't use a gate resistor and your MOSFET switches in 5ns trouble is to be expected. So probe the output with a scope and adjust the gate resistor to get a nice slow rise time without ringing, something like 1V/µs.

If possible, the current setting resistor should be on the source end and on the switched side, so it limits the current spike when charging the cable capacitance, but that's much less critical.

In the cable, return current should be close to forward current to minimize the area of the current loop. So you can put the return wire in the middle of the ribbon, or several return wires at regular intervals, not all on the same side of the ribbon. If current is high you may have to use several wires anyway, otherwise wire resistance means lighting a LED will dim the others.


If you put a few decoupling caps between the power rail and ground next to the connector, they're tied together at high frequency so it doesn't matter whether you switch the LEDs high or low side.
PWM with constant current during the ON-time (as some LED drivers do) has the same issues minus the current spike at turn-on to charge the wire and LED capacitances.
Adjustable constant current is DC so it has no issues at all with EMI, but it needs more parts: filter the PWM into DC, then an opamp and a pass transistor.

Second question first. PWM drive definitely introduces EMI to the mix. It can be managed using several techniques:

Limit the slew rate of your PWM switching (especially the off-to-on transition)
minimize wire loop area to the LED
Add common-mode filtering to the LED wire

High side vs. low side drive? This makes less of a difference. Controlling high-side could be slightly better as this avoids some power noise making its way onto your external wiring.
A proposed low-EMI solution would use:

constant-current driver or slew-limited PWM on the high side
bypass cap between LED drive and GND before the cable connector
twisted pair cable to the LED
common mode filter (e.g., ferrite bead) the pair

The constant-current driver could itself be a PWM  to keep your efficiency up, followed by an integrating filter (pi section, etc.) and the other stuff above to keep your EMI down.
Here's an idea to make a constant-current driver controlled by PWM: How to make a proportional current output on a constant current driver with PWM dimming

would it make sense to add filtering like a ferrite bead or a bypass capacitor to the external pcb side too?

The LED isn’t a radiating item, so no.

High-side or low-side drive won't make a difference in this case. From the perspective of the radiated emissions, the impact is contingent on the edge rates (how quickly you're switching the load on and off) and the inductance the current loop presents. From first principles, inductance is a measure of how much magnetic field you produce for a given amount of current, after all!
Constant current drive will be superior to PWM here for EMC performance, but with a few catches. The former will probably implement some switching element upstream with a substantial filter. There will still be a switching node that can cause trouble if you're not careful with layout here. Same rules apply: minimize inductance and the dI/dt. If you're going with PWM drive, try to limit the slew rates i.e. the rate at which the current increases. If implementing this via an open drain N-FET, the slew can be adjusted by adding a gate drive resistor, which is in series with the gate. This is because the faster the edge rises, the more harmonic content and energy is being fed into the inductance of the LED loop.
Another aspect worth mentioning is the construction of the cable. Minimizing inductance here can be done by keeping the forward and return path conductors as close as possible. Twisting the pair together can also help since this helps further cancel out field that would normally present "inside" the loop of wire.
